# curl can't connect to neo4j - curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

Tags: curl, neo4j

From time to time I don't get neo4j responses from API. Library (which uses libcurl) reports connection error. Neo4j (3.1.0) runs on localhost, so no network issues are involved. Webconsole is responsive all the time.

I can reproduce the issue using simple bash command:

```
$ while true; do curl -X POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/; done
```

Most of the time I get expected:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : "Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized",
    "message" : "No authentication header supplied."
  }
```

But from time to time:

```
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

Is my neo4j not dealing correctly with too many requests? I have no idea how to tweak it or if I miss anything in the config. I use the default one.

Answer (score 0):

well, I cannot explain why it works when it works (most of time) but the error message says authentication header. 
That is, HTTP header for the query, that should contain the token returned by the server on replying to the login event.

So basicly, a -H parameter is needed to your curl call

Try to logout from the webconsole and see if all curl calls fail.
imho, this is dealt automagically by the neo team but when the token expires you get errors before its automagically working again.

try your curl from another machine, with no webconsole opened too (cache cleaned too maybe).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case here. when I do: $ curl -X post 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/' --user 'user:password' sometimes it returns curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server.

Comment: Not sure --user is correct, imho would be -H key:value
Look with the chrome devtools  (F12) and the 'network' tab, that will show you the details of the requests and responses.

However, try  :server connect  in the browser.
But clear cache just to be sure.